# Overcoming Extra Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have to INSERT multiple columns from different tables but keep having the same problem.

The problem is this: I can INSERT the column from TableA.ColumnA into TableB.ColumnA no problem. But next I need to INSERT TableC.columnA into TableB.columnB and this INSERT command adds extra rows are  that change the id's of the data.

My insert commands, plus the UPDATE command I was executing to get the id's to match (unsuccessfully) is below.

I know that the insert command can add extra rows but how do I get passed this so that the id's match?

I thought that maybe the columns had auto increment set but they do not -- so that does not seem to be the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
(1) INSERT INTO users_posts 
           (author_id, 
            post_id, 
            post_title)  
    SELECT contents.user_id, contents.id, contents.title 
    FROM contents 
    WHERE contents.id = id

(2) INSERT INTO users_posts 
           (post_content)  
    SELECT content_bodies.content 
    FROM content_bodies 
    WHERE content_bodies.id = id

(3) UPDATE users_posts 
    SET post_content  = (SELECT content_bodies.content  
                         FROM content_bodies  
                         WHERE content_bodies.id = users_posts.post_id)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the beginning and ending states of the relevant rows in these tables?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @JesseSmith Thank you for your reply. I will get this data.

Comment: @JavaDevil Thank you also for your reply. My DBMS is MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, you do not actually want your second and third statements, but rather just an update statement to update `users_posts.post_content`

If you do an insert it is always (assuming it doesn't fail for other reasons i.e. constraints) insert new rows, Hence the keyword `INSERT`.

Try this statement which adds the post content to the `users_posts` table from the `content_bodies` table based on the ids!

```
UPDATE users_posts AS u 
JOIN content_bodies AS b 
ON b.id = u.post_id 
SET u.post_content = b.content;
```

See it in action with this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b96d0)

**Edit**

Please run this query and let me know if it matches data correctly

```
SELECT * FROM users_posts u
JOIN content_bodies AS b 
ON b.id = u.post_id
```

Comment: TIL about SQLFiddle! That's super-awesome, Java Devil!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Java Devil. You are right that I can do without my second and third statements above. I tried your suggested statement but MYSQL returned "zero rows affected" -- the data from content_bodies was not added to the post_content column in the users_posts table. Any further suggestions you have would be very helpful.

Comment: @cspannoyannis See my edit above, but without some example data it will be hard to see why it didnt work, I suspect Id's don't match.